# ServletOutputStream does not throw exception when client aborts

Tags: tomcat7

Hi i have the following construct in my Tomcat-Webapp

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
final PrintStream p = new PrintStream(out, true, "UTF-8");
while (condition) {
    p.println(StringUtils.join(values, ","));
    logger.debug("Exported line");
}
```

but when i close the requesting browser, the code continues to end, even when it takes several minutes and writes several megabytes.

I would expect that the ServletOutputStream whould throw an exception when the client is disconnected and the code tries to write data into it.

the ServletOutputStream is a

```
org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream[delegate=org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream@7fcdb6bc]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok it tourned out that PrintStream covers underlying exceptions:

```
public void write(byte buf[], int off, int len) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            out.write(buf, off, len);
            if (autoFlush)
                out.flush();
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

so i have to check for errors manually by calling

```
p.checkError()
```